# Why buttonfield is not working ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am have put buttonfield in gridview. It hit the rowcommand event and goes to the end of block but doesn't do what it is supposed to do. It is supposed to assign text to the text box and shows message via response.write but doesn't. In debugger it perfectly assign text to the textbox and goes to the message but nothing on interface side. Why ?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewContractorTypes" OnRowCommand="grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractorTypeName" HeaderText="Contractor Type" />
                                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />


                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

event:

```
protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "edit")
            {
                byte ContractorTypeID = Convert.ToByte(grdviewContractorTypes.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);

                //HFActID.Value = ID.ToString();

                btnAddContractorType.Visible = false;
                btnUpdate.Visible = true;

                DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeID(ContractorTypeID);
                DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];

                txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = r["ContractorTypeName"].ToString();

                Response.Write("DONE");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

It doesn't do anything, apparently but shows and assigns in debugger. Why ?

Comment: If your code throws an exception, you'll never know.  Perhaps start there...

Comment: oh wait, after reaching to the end of event, it goes to the Application_Error block but before that it cover whole event then it should have done it's task, why not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding OnRowEditing to your grid.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdviewContractorTypes" OnRowEditing="grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing" OnRowCommand="grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_ContractorTypes_ContractorTypeID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractorTypeName" HeaderText="Contractor Type" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="edit" ImageUrl="~/assets/global/images/shopping/edit.png" ButtonType="Image" ControlStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-Height="25px" />


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "edit")
            {
                byte ContractorTypeID = Convert.ToByte(grdviewContractorTypes.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);

                //HFActID.Value = ID.ToString();

                //btnAddContractorType.Visible = false;
                //btnUpdate.Visible = true;

                //DataTable dt = MngContractorTypes.SelectContractorTypesByContractorTypeID(ContractorTypeID);
                //DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];

                //txtBoxContractorTypeName.Text = r["ContractorTypeName"].ToString();

                Response.Write("DONE");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
         // code to edit
    }
```

Comment: sorry that didn't work 

No overload for 'grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventHandler'

Comment: Do you bind your grid within page_load event?

Comment: The 'No overload for 'grdviewContractorTypes_RowEditing' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventHandler'' error seems to be a different issue as it is working on my side. Unless I'm missing something entirely.

Comment: HAHA oh man the row_editing worked, though it's empty but it did. THanks a lot man but i don't understand WHY ?